# my transitions doesnt trigger on input check, but my events do

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations, css-transitions

im trying to make a modal menu that cames with a smooth transition from the side at the time the burguer menu is clicked, it works but the transition doesnt fire, but if i run live server and make the changes live the transitions do applied, can somebody help me out?

here's the live site so you can check it out
https://silkiercomet.github.io/audiphile-starter/

heres the css

```
.modal {
visibility: hidden;
pointer-events: none;
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: auto; 
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

}

```
#mobile-menu:checked ~ .modal{
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin-left: auto; 
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%; 
    height: 100%;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;

  }
  #mobile-menu:checked ~ .modal .modal-content{
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically it's impossible to trigger a transition without the change of a class through JS, i was trying to do it with only CSS but thats simple not posible due to the document work flow

Answer (score 1):

So here is a basic example that should work for you. I think part of the issue is you have the modal div hidden which I know can mess with animations

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
 menu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
#toggle {
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
}

.content { 
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #ddd;
}

#menu { 
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99;
display: flex;
pointer-events: none;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
opacity: 0;
}

#menu .navigation {
width: 600px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #aaa;
margin-left: -600px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

#menu.active {
opacity: 1;
}

#menu.active .navigation { 
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<button id="toggle">Toggle Menu</button>
</div>

<div id="menu">

<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
<li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>

</div>
```